# How do I make the question community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki, asking-questions

How do I make the question community wiki? I don't see such a button

Comment: Just bribe a moderator. They'll happily do it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You no longer can, because everyone can edit your post when necessary and it isn't supposed to be used as a loophole to allow questions that would otherwise be off-topic.

Only moderators can manually change it to a community wiki if you insist on having it changed

Comment: Does it still change automatically if too many different people edit it?

Comment: [Yes I believe so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)